# Profile Layout in civi on Joomla

Tags: profile, joomla

Need help with Contribution pages profile layout.
It is not related to the template i am using, it is in civi

Profiles come with label on one line then field on line below, I've tried looking in
administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/profile
Can't figure it out, can anyone help me get the label and field on same line?
Will pay.
Joomla 3.7.4/civicrm 4.7.18

Comment: Karen, I imagine you've probably solved this by now. But if not, can you confirm that your contribution page on the Joomla front-end is loading without errors (failed to load resource, JS) in the browser console? At present, testing with Joomla 3.8.1 + CiviCRM 4.7.24 and the default Protostar template I have the fields displaying next to the label on the same line.
I have had to deal with this in the past thought. One reason that it can occur is an incorrect Resource URL setting (and I've seen a few people with Joomla discussing problems with Resource URL recently so there may be a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the template file - but I think this is best handled in CSS.  See this Stack Overflow question: [HTML form with side by side input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488447/html-form-with-side-by-side-input-fields).

If you aren't CSS-savvy, you can hire someone from https://civicrm.org/providers or ask on https://chat.civicrm.org for someone.  Note also that while having a CiviCRM-specific person is nice, this issue isn't one that really requires CiviCRM-specific knowledge.  Any decent front-end web developer (and most web designers) should be able to handle this.

Finally, to ensure your CSS isn't overwritten by an upgrade, put it into civicrm.css and specify the path to it at **Administer menu » System Settings » Resource URLs** under *Custom CSS URL*.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I did work within the template css and got it on the same line, not ideal but better, thank you.
I will test in my sandbox on 3.8.1 (haven't upgraded yet) and will give you results of testing. Will also check the resource URL.

Comment: My name's not Andrew - but glad I could help!  Please mark this as the answer if it's what solved the problem for you.  Finally, please note that Joomla 3.8 has some compatibility issues with Civi - see [CRM-21203](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203).